# How to move content from one user control to another, windows forms, c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I know almost the same thing was asked on this site, but I can't figure out the solution for my particular problem. So i'm trying to set up a nice fast-food shop for the end of an beginners course in C#. The restaurant has to be created in Windows Forms. Basically, I used user controls to give it a nicer look, and in one user control named "menu", I added panels containing pictures, price, information and an "Order now" button of the products. I have another user control named "See order", where I want to show the panels of the products which i pressed "order now" on. Basically I just want to move the panel I select from one user control to another and I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

Comment: i also tried creating a new panel and just assigning the panel i want to it but i don't have the knowledge to code that in button_click and i also didn't think it would work for 2-3 products.

Comment: My WinForms experience is a bit dusty, but as I remember it was not possible to change the parent of a component once it has been initialized. I'd say destroying the old one and creating a new one in the right place would be the best fit.

Comment: All right, thank you, i ll try and do that.

Comment: @Cip:          Maybe, instead of the second usercontrol, you can use a TableLayoutPanel and add your UserControl to that TableLayoutPanel. It would be easier.